# Issues in Search, Indexes, Lucene in Orchard CMS

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms-1.7

I am using Orchard v.1.7.1.0... i have a website with Terra theme... it have a search button i have installed all the three subjected modules for searching purposes... as per tutorials i have done all as it says for searching the content and titles... The problem comes when i follow the tutorial for search and indexing... it says to check the content which you want to search from the SEARCH tab under SETTING tab in the dashboard (Admin Panel)... but there is no list to check from...

why is that so... and how can i resolve this issue... as i need to make something from the search button...

thanks in advance for help

Comment: Some one to respond me Please... i cannot get any solution online for that

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have a superb working solution for your query. I also have a tutorial as well on the same issue.
Here is the link - http://www.pepfry.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-search-feature-in-orchard-cms.

Follow the tutorial and you will succeed in enabling search feature successfully.
Additionally, Please feel free to ask me questions regarding this issue.

Regards!
Sumesh M.S

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot see any fields under search settings is because you haven't added any content type to the Index.

What you need to do is go to "Edit Content Type" in Content Type definitions and mark "Index this content type in:". Then you will have fields available in search settings, with title and body automatically marked.